# Android OS 13 permission updates

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-13

My android app is working fine on devices with OS 12 and below but the same is throwing a message "Please manually change permissions from phone settings" for device with OS 13 though at the begining all location and storage permissions are granted. This message is triggered when user denies any permission. I added the new permissions READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, and READ_MEDIA_AUDIO in manifest file but still unable to use the app due to the above message. What could I be missing out? Please guide.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Datafields.sPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FileMainPage.this, new String[]{Datafields.sPermission}, Datafields.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
                // If any permission above not allowed by user, this condition will execute every time, else your else part will work
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FileLeave.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == Datafields.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("denial of permssion");
            String permission = permissions[0];
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                boolean showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);
                if (!showRationale) {
                    Toast.makeText(FileMainPage.this, "please manually change the permissions from Phone settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

        }
    }
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="in.globalspace.android.gst_communicator_permission" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: `"Please manually change permissions from phone settings".` Never saw that message. Where does it come from?

Comment: @blackapps - Hi, I have updated my question, sorry for incorrect info earlier

Comment: You should not talk abou your message alone. You should explain why and when your app displays a message. Now you let it to us to decode your code and find out what is going on. Tell us what happens!

Comment: We cannot even zee and you did not tell when this happens. Which permission are you requesting? All is unknown.

Comment: @blackapps - I have stated "This message is triggered when user denies any permission"..